# Querying data from multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have dynamic databases being added everyday to my system.

the name always follows this pattern:

```
NAME_YYYYMMDD1200
```

and the tables inside it are the same.

How can I query [SELECT statement] all column for myTable for the last 5 days databases?

For example, if today is 10-OCT-2013, I query all columns for myTable for these DBs:

```
NAME_201310101200
NAME_201310091200
NAME_201310081200
NAME_201310071200
NAME_201310061200
```

I try `SELECT * FROM NAME_*.myTable` but it oubviusly doesn't work.

How can I have a [SELECT] query DB name dynamic/built on the fly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute your query in each database [sp_msForEachDb](http://www.sqllion.com/2010/08/for-each-database-sp_msforeachdb/).

You can filter databases like this:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
@command1='IF ''?''
IN (''AdventureWorks2012'',''AdventureWorks2012_test'')
BEGIN
       select * from [?].sys.schemas
END'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would my query look like? Do you have an example on a simple select on all DBs?

Comment: I have a link in my answer.  Here is an example from this link "EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 'select * from [?].sys.schemas'"

Comment: This won't work because of the sys DBs. It will try to find a table called myTable there but there's no such a table there. How can I filter the tables names?

Comment: Link in answer is dead.